# NHibernate 2nd Level Cache issue with QueryOver

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have 2nd level cache working perfectly when I use Session.Get() however if I use the new QueryOver API in NH3.0 the cache does not get hit.

This works perfectly:

```
public TEntity Get(int id)
{
  return session.Get<TEntity>(id);
}
```

This does not hit the cache:

```
public TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity bool>> filter)
{
    var query = _session.QueryOver<TEntity>()
                .Where(filter);

    query.Cacheable();     
    return query.SingleOrDefault();
}
```

I'm using transactions to make sure the 2nd level cache is used correctly.

Here is my Session configuration:

```
Session = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory().ShowSql())
                .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Activity>())
                .Cache(c => c.UseSecondLevelCache()
                            .UseQueryCache()
                            .ProviderClass<NHibernate.Cache.HashtableCacheProvider>())
                .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => configuration = cfg)
                .BuildSessionFactory()
                .OpenSession();
```

I'm setting my entities for cache usage:

```
public class CommentMap : ClassMap<Comment>
    {
        public CommentMap()
        {
            Cache.ReadWrite();

            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.Message);
            References(x => x.Activity);
            References(x => x.User);
        }
    }
```

I'm calling the Cacheable method on my QueryOver queries:

```
public TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
        {
            var query = _session.QueryOver<TEntity>()
                .Where(filter);

            query
                .Cacheable();

            return query.SingleOrDefault();
        }
```

I must be missing something, just can't figure out what.

Comment: Note to any readers after me! The question seems to have been edited to reflect the correct implementation, thats probaly why Diegos answer is marked correct...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several related issues:

- `Session.Load` **never** hits the DB, so it's not a proof that caching is working
- Query cache is enabled separately from entity cache
- Query caching is explicit: you have to tell NHibernate to cache that `QueryOver` using the `Cacheable()` method

Also, make sure you have entity caching for the entities whose queries you'll be caching. Otherwise cache will make things worse.

Comment: I do have the query and entity caches enabled and I'm calling Cacheable() method on QueryOver. I'll check monday your list against the code to see if I missed something. Thanks.

Comment: In the end, what was the problem? Was it that you had query.Cacheable() followed by returning query.SingleOrDefault() (rather than doing query = query.Cacheable())? Or did you find something else.